# script to check whether select query is returning value or not?

Tags: php, html

I want to check whether select query is returning some values or not.

```
if(!empty($_POST['sign']))
{
    $e=$_POST['email'];
    $p-$_POST['password'];
    $selquery="select * from login where email_id='$e' and password='$p'";
    $r=mysql_query($selquery);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the sql query result, do the following:

```
 $r = mysql_query ($selquery);
 echo '$a = $r';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mysql_num_rows() function to retrieve a count and see if it's larger than 0.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    // do something
}
```

However, you really shouldn't use mysql_* functions anymore, since they will soon be deprecated. Instead, you should use PDO or mysqli!

You can read more about why not to use these functions here: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

And a comparison of PDO vs mysqli is here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Comment: i edited the code but now every time it is giving invalid userif(!empty($_POST['sign']))
 {
  $e=$_POST['email'];
  $p-$_POST['password'];
  $selquery="select * from login where email_id='$e' and password='$p'";
  $r=mysql_query($selquery);
  if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) 
  {
  $result=mysql_query($selquery);
  $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $id=$row['id'];
  header("location:index.php?uid=$id");
  }
 else
 {
  echo "Invalid username";
 }
 }